# Crossing Blades. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I cross blades, but with no adversary.
>
> I am sharp, but I am still entrusted to children without thought.
>
> I turn one into two, two into four. But never vice-versa.

Who am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Answer:

> Scissors

Reasoning:

> Blades cross paths to cut.
>  Cuts things up, which divides them.

Comment: DESPERATELY TYPED THE ANSWER, KNEW OTHERS WOULD GET IT QUICK

Comment: Why could it not go the other way? (4)x(½)=2. This is a good solution, but not the one I am looking for.

Comment: Is it the addition?

Comment: Another good idea, but I'm not thinking within the realm of mathematics. I will add another line if I need to.

Comment: @HankoTanks Seems too broad then...

Comment: I'll update my question.

Comment: @HankoTanks new answer :D

Comment: I also thought Scissors once I read the question, but as this is already ticked, I guess not to enter answer : ( . I was late :'(

Comment: You trust children with scissors without thought?